# C# bring Form to Front following File Dialog

Tags: c#, forms, active-window

When I start up the program I have added code to open a file dialog box, but doing this results in the main form being sent behind Visual Studio(and other open programs) once a file has been selected.
I have tried using `this.BringToFront()` but this doesn't seem to work.
The program currently only has one form as well, how would I bring this to the front when the program starts?

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    InitialiseDataGrid();
    selectFile();
    readData();
    this.BringToFront();
}
```

`selectFile()` is a function that selects a file using a file dialog box,
`readData()` is a function that reads the data from the text file into a `dataGridView`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should past the owner window's instance while Opening The dialog window. example code:

```
var file = new OpenFileDialog();
file.ShowDialog(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
this.TopMost = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're juggling with different applications: VS and your program. The released version of the program probably won't run through VS anyway.

Bring it to the foreground:

```
this.Activate();
```

Use it with [caution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).